# Preparing Items List Of Sql-Table

Tags: sql

I am having data of table dummy as below:

```
Name                       amount      amount1
-----------------------------------------------
mahesh                     1200        Null
mahesh                     1000        Null
mahesh                     Null        25000
mahendra                   1200        Null
Kirti                      null        22000
```

I am trying to prepare a list like below:

```
Name                       amount      amount1
-----------------------------------------------
mahesh                                 22800
mahendra                   1200
kirti                                  22000
```

How to do it?
what is sql transact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're adding numbers where `amount` is negative and `amount1` is positive.  You can do that with a `group by`.  A `case` can help place the resulting `sum` in the right column:

```
select  name
,       case 
        when sum(amount1 - amount) < 0 then -sum(amount1 - amount) 
        end as amount
,       case 
        when sum(amount1 - amount) >= 0 then sum(amount1 - amount) 
        end as amount1
from    YourTable
group by
       name
```

Comment: yes your idea is click upto some points but my freinds you are missing table name and coalesce or is null function

Comment: ... also your code showing of result of mahendra in -1200 amount and I don't want negative sign on it.

Comment: @mahesh: I've added the `from` clause, and made the first column positive

Comment: Your Idea is clicked hence I accept it and give you first preference for the same also I hereby accept your answer with my corrected solution.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution is inspired by Andomar with Coalesce Function as under:

```
select  name,       
case 
when sum(coalesce(amount1,0) - coalesce(amount,0)) < 0 
then -sum(coalesce(amount1,0) - coalesce(amount,0)) 
end 
as amount,       
case 
when sum(coalesce(amount1,0) - coalesce(amount,0)) >= 0 
then sum(coalesce(amount1,0) - coalesce(amount,0)) 
end 
as amount1
from dummy
group by
name
```

**The COALESCE Or ISNULL Function is require for count first nullable columns.**
otherwise your result should remain as **NULL**